# As like as "Bootstrap" is for "HTML/CSS/JS", do flutter have any kind of open source for pre built widgets?

Tags: flutter, bootstrap-4, widget

Similar to BOOTSTRAP, being a beginner learning Flutter, I would like to know whether there are any open sources for pre-built widgets so I can use them in my project.

I would like to know the availability for pre-build lines of code, like for creating forms and tables, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

flutter provide open source platform to build widget like **BOOTSTRAP** and which is **[Flutter Flow](https://flutterflow.io/)**

Comment: Thanks for you to find some time and helping me to answer this, as you suggested I have explored Flutter Flow, a great and very useful product, but I am asking about any open-source platform for "Flutter", that provides code bases for certain components.